# libGDX crashes after exporting it to a jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, libgdx

I'm making a project and it works when I run it, but after I try to plug my phone to the computer and run it (I even tried to use the emulator) it will say immediately that it stopped. About desktop version, again, it works when I run it, but after I make it a JAR file it crashes immediately.

why does it work through intellij but not through real files? anyway, here is the logcat:

```
08-10 22:37:57.639  21323-21323/com.ak01.flappysquid.android I/art﹕ Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
08-10 22:37:57.710  21323-21323/com.ak01.flappysquid.android I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.042.016_msm8226_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1__release_AU ()
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.00
    Build Date: 02/11/15 Wed
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch: quic/LA.BF.1.1.1_rb1.10
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.042.016 + 62ca4eb + acd831d + 9f8b442 + e027a02 + cba30ba + 53c303a + a649d79 + 23e16f8 + 5e97da7 + cbd2a44 + 33d072a + 7aacf06 + 72b33e7 + 28f6f60 + b4c13d8 +  NOTHING
08-10 22:37:57.739  21323-21323/com.ak01.flappysquid.android I/AndroidInput﹕ sensor listener setup
08-10 22:37:57.746  21323-21345/com.ak01.flappysquid.android D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
08-10 22:37:57.756  21323-21323/com.ak01.flappysquid.android D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
08-10 22:37:57.771  21323-21323/com.ak01.flappysquid.android I/AndroidInput﹕ sensor listener tear down
08-10 22:37:57.796  21323-21345/com.ak01.flappysquid.android I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.042.016_msm8226_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1__release_AU ()
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.00
    Build Date: 02/11/15 Wed
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch: quic/LA.BF.1.1.1_rb1.10
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.042.016 + 62ca4eb + acd831d + 9f8b442 + e027a02 + cba30ba + 53c303a + a649d79 + 23e16f8 + 5e97da7 + cbd2a44 + 33d072a + 7aacf06 + 72b33e7 + 28f6f60 + b4c13d8 +  NOTHING
08-10 22:37:57.796  21323-21345/com.ak01.flappysquid.android I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-10 22:37:57.812  21323-21345/com.ak01.flappysquid.android D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
08-10 22:38:06.131  21323-21323/com.ak01.flappysquid.android I/AndroidInput﹕ sensor listener setup
08-10 22:38:06.141  21323-21341/com.ak01.flappysquid.android W/GL2JNIView﹕ creating OpenGL ES 2.0 context
08-10 22:38:06.175  21323-21341/com.ak01.flappysquid.android I/GL2﹕ all initialized 2
08-10 22:38:06.175  21323-21341/com.ak01.flappysquid.android I/AndroidGraphics﹕ OGL renderer: Adreno (TM) 305
08-10 22:38:06.175  21323-21341/com.ak01.flappysquid.android I/AndroidGraphics﹕ OGL vendor: Qualcomm
08-10 22:38:06.175  21323-21341/com.ak01.flappysquid.android I/AndroidGraphics﹕ OGL version: OpenGL ES 3.0 V@84.0 AU@05.00.02.042.016 (CL@)
08-10 22:38:06.175  21323-21341/com.ak01.flappysquid.android I/AndroidGraphics﹕ OGL extensions: GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture GL_AMD_performance_monitor GL_AMD_program_binary_Z400 GL_EXT_debug_label GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_EXT_robustness GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV GL_NV_fence GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap GL_OES_fragment_precision_high GL_OES_get_program_binary GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_texture_3D GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_vertex_type_10_10_10_2 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_QCOM_alpha_test GL_QCOM_binning_control GL_QCOM_driver_control GL_QCOM_perfmon_global_mode GL_QCOM_extended_get GL_QCOM_extended_get2 GL_QCOM_tiled_rendering GL_QCOM_writeonly_rendering GL_EXT_sRGB GL_EXT_sRGB_write_control GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture GL_EXT_color_buffer_float GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query
08-10 22:38:06.176  21323-21341/com.ak01.flappysquid.android W/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglGetConfigAttrib:632>: EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
08-10 22:38:06.179  21323-21341/com.ak01.flappysquid.android W/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglGetConfigAttrib:632>: EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
08-10 22:38:06.179  21323-21341/com.ak01.flappysquid.android I/AndroidGraphics﹕ framebuffer: (5, 6, 5, 0)
08-10 22:38:06.179  21323-21341/com.ak01.flappysquid.android I/AndroidGraphics﹕ depthbuffer: (16)
08-10 22:38:06.179  21323-21341/com.ak01.flappysquid.android I/AndroidGraphics﹕ stencilbuffer: (0)
08-10 22:38:06.179  21323-21341/com.ak01.flappysquid.android I/AndroidGraphics﹕ samples: (0)
08-10 22:38:06.179  21323-21341/com.ak01.flappysquid.android I/AndroidGraphics﹕ coverage sampling: (false)
08-10 22:38:06.243  21323-21341/com.ak01.flappysquid.android I/AndroidGraphics﹕ Managed meshes/app: { }
08-10 22:38:06.243  21323-21341/com.ak01.flappysquid.android I/AndroidGraphics﹕ Managed textures/app: { }
08-10 22:38:06.243  21323-21341/com.ak01.flappysquid.android I/AndroidGraphics﹕ Managed cubemap/app: { }
08-10 22:38:06.249  21323-21341/com.ak01.flappysquid.android I/AndroidGraphics﹕ Managed shaders/app: { }
08-10 22:38:06.252  21323-21341/com.ak01.flappysquid.android I/AndroidGraphics﹕ Managed buffers/app: { }
08-10 22:38:06.367  21323-21341/com.ak01.flappysquid.android E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 56397
    Process: com.ak01.flappysquid.android, PID: 21323
    com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: squiddy.png
            at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:140)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.TextureData$Factory.loadFromFile(TextureData.java:98)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:100)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:92)
            at com.ak01.flappysquid.Assets.load(Assets.java:53)
            at com.ak01.flappysquid.FlappySquid.create(FlappySquid.java:12)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:241)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1511)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1239)
     Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error reading file: squiddy.png (Internal)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.read(AndroidFileHandle.java:77)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:222)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:137)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.TextureData$Factory.loadFromFile(TextureData.java:98)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:100)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:92)
            at com.ak01.flappysquid.Assets.load(Assets.java:53)
            at com.ak01.flappysquid.FlappySquid.create(FlappySquid.java:12)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:241)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1511)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1239)
     Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: squiddy.png
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:313)
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:287)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.read(AndroidFileHandle.java:75)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:222)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:137)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.TextureData$Factory.loadFromFile(TextureData.java:98)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:100)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:92)
            at com.ak01.flappysquid.Assets.load(Assets.java:53)
            at com.ak01.flappysquid.FlappySquid.create(FlappySquid.java:12)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:241)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1511)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1239)
08-10 22:38:09.465  21323-21341/com.ak01.flappysquid.android I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 21323 SIG: 9
```

Also, is there a way to save the log for the JAR file?

edit: please tell me if you need more (or less) information.

**Edit: solved it with the android (it now runs on my phone) but it still won't work as a JAR file. is there a way to save a log for it?**

Comment: i'm stuck on this alot of time please help

Comment: Where is the `squiddy.png` file? The Exception stack clearly points that this file is missing.

Comment: Actually last time it showed me the same thing with squiddy2.png, and yes they are both in the assets folder. They both start with a capital letter (at the actual file), does it matter?

Comment: Wow!!!! i changed it to a capital letter and it actually worked!!!!